# finding ordinary and regular singular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a little confused by how I find ordinary and regular singular points of a differential equation. Given $$4xu'' + 2u' + \lambda u = 0$$

How would I go about finding whether $x=0$ is a singular or ordinary point. I understand the intuition behind it but am unsure how I can apply it particularly in showing a function is analytic at said point.

Comment: Do you know the definitions of ordinary points and singular points?  Regular and irregular singular points?  What have you got from checking those conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Consider the general homogeneous second order linear differential equation $$u''+P(x)u'+Q(x)u=0$$
>   where $x \in D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.
>
> The point $x_0 \in D$ is said to be an **ordinary point** of the above given differential equation if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$.
>
> If either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ fails to be analytic at $x_0$, the point $x_0$ is called a **singular point** of the given differential equation.
>
> A singular point $x_0$ of the given differential equation is said to be **regular singular point** if the function $(x-x_0)P(x)$ and $(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$ and **irregular** otherwise.

${}$

$4xu'' + 2u' + \lambda u = 0\implies u'' + \frac{u'}{2x} + \frac{\lambda}{4x} u = 0$

Comparing the equation with $u''+P(x)u'+Q(x)u=0$ we have $P(x)=\frac{1}{2x} $ and $Q(x)=\frac{\lambda}{4x}$

Clearly $x=0$ is the only singular point of the given differential equation.

Since $$(x-x_0)P(x)=x \frac{1}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}$$ and

$$(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)=x^2 \frac{\lambda}{4x}=\frac{\lambda x}{4}$$

so both are analytic at $x=0$, and hence $x=0$ is regular singular point.